# Feeds import value to Entity Reference?

Tags: entities, feeds

How can i import value to Entity Reference using Feeds?

I have this in Feeds (CSV):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMEI4.jpg
```

I tried all of this options but everytime the field is empty.

Importing data is a value like this.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6dMJ.png
```

Also i tried «Tamper: Convert string into entity ID» but there is no field in Entity View that i need.

This is how node field is configured:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcGBY.png
```

And this is Tamper config:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta4cE.png
```